# Scroll top based on the click of attribute data-menuanchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/sh8tmba6/1/

There is a navigation bar with years in the ul>li list. Each li has `<a>` tag with attribute `data-menuanchor`. When a user clicks on these links based on `data-menuanchor` the respective div must scroll to the top.

Note: Here the navigation bar must be fixed even when scrolled up or down

Here is the jquery code which I tried, but it is not working as per the requirement

```
  ('.timeline-nav li a').on('click', function (e) {
     var yearID = '#' + $(this).data('menuanchor') ;
  $('.historyWrapper').animate({
        scrollTop: $(yearID).offset().top - $(yearID).parent().offset().top + $(yearID).parent().scrollTop()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        specialEasing: {
            width: 'linear',
            height: 'easeOutBounce'
        }
    });
   });
```

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want exactly? to make a transition when clicking?

Comment: "not working as per the requirement" - can you be more specific?

Comment: @pharesdiego The div must scroll to the respective year. If I click on 2014, then 2014 div must scroll to top and the navigation bar must be fixed.

Comment: So... the scrolling is obiously already working and now what you want us to do is to code the sticky header part for you?

Comment: @Connum yes exactly. Scroll is also not proper if you see my last comment

Comment: Too bad that SO is not a free coding service. You'll have to put a little more effort in it yourself. Find out how sticky functionality is achieved in general, then come back if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Yes, I do have a specific problem. I have tried my code. But I am stuck in the reverse case. Hence I posted here